# How to close the current window in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using JavaFX to build an application. In some windows there's a button whose purpose is to **close the current one**. Currently I'm using this kind of approach, but I think it's not *clean* as I would like it to be.

```
public class AboutController {
    @FXML
    private Button aboutClose;

    public void initialize() {
        aboutClose.setOnAction(event ->
            ((Stage) (aboutClose.getScene().getWindow())).close());
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to implement this task? How to get the stage I'm working on from the Controller without having to take it from the button itself?

Comment: In my opinion, what you’re doing is fine, except that [close() is identical to hide()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#close--), so I would do away with casting to Stage, and just call hide() instead of close().

Comment: Just be aware that in initialize, the parent scene hasn't been set on each component yet. Since your code is in an onAction() it should work but anytime you need to access the parent scene directly in the initialize() method, you should use Platform.runLater()

Comment: @Steve There's absolutely no guarantee that a runnable passed to `Platform.runLater(...)` in `initialize()` would be executed at a time that the root of the FXML had been added to a scene. If you need to write code outside of an event handler in the `initialize()` method that access the scene when it is available, you should register a listener with some node's `sceneProperty()` and execute the code when the scene changes (to a non-null value). In this case, it's completely irrelevant, of course, since the user can't press a button that's not in a scene.